# How to cancel remove event in Select2 plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to cancel remove event in Select2 like this

```
$('#dropdownOne').on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
    alert(this.value);
    if (this.value != 4) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: I just visited the Select2 documentation page (https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control). It says, "`select2:unselect` is fired whenever a result is unselected. `select2:unselecting` is fired before this and can be prevented."

Comment: It's working , thank you :) , but the problem is this.value doesn't show the real value because dropdownOne needs to update after removing any item, can you please help me to update it after removing

Comment: I would like to help you, but I don't understand what you are asking. Could you try re-phrasing your question and detailing the expected behaviour? Thanks.